# Safari 7 infinite POST request

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, post, safari7

I've get stuck with such issue. I have a form. When user submits his data, I'm sending some data via post ajax request. On success I set some data to hidden form, which has action pointing to current url subdomain, but in fact to partner site url that is set over CNAME. Then I trigger jQuery submit event on this hidden form, so after response user is on partner site (hidden form has no target attribute). It works fine in any browser except Safari 7 on mac. It just [load for infinite time.](http://prntscr.com/6rxvsv) 
Any help is appreciated.

Well, there's not much code. Onsuccess of I run this:

```
if (response.result === true) {
    this.targets.login.$email.val(response.data.data.email);
    this.targets.login.$password.val(response.data.data.password);
    this.targets.login.$form.submit();
}
```

My hidden form looks like this:

```
<form action="http://someurlunderCNAME" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
    <input type="text" name="data[User][email]">
    <input type="password" name="data[User][password]">
</form>
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've got it myself. The reason was triggering submit on form. And the 'correct' behaiviour is to trigger click on submit input (which, btw, should be added too)